# It is unable to get of an apex class for getting ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId from the following code?

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I need an apex class to get a standard object called Contentdocumentlink field called LinkedEntityId.
when document upload. It should automatically create a task.
I'm unable to get  ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId by using this code.
This my code:

```
    trigger CreateTask on ContentVersion (after insert)
    {​​​​​​​​
    List<Task> insertTask = new List<Task>();
    Task newTask = new Task();
    for(ContentVersion newCase : Trigger.new)
    {​​​​​​​​
    newTask.subject = 'Document Expiration';
    newTask.ActivityDate = newCase.Expiry_Date__c;
    newTask.ownerId = newCase.OwnerId;
    newTask.status = 'Not started';
    newTask.Priority = 'Normal';
    if('ObjAPiName' == 'Contact')
    {​​​​​​​​
    newTask.WhoId = //Contact ;
    }​​​​​​​​
    else
    {​​​​​​​​
    
    newTask.WhatId =[select LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink where ContentDocumentId IN : newCase.ContentDocumentId].Id; 

// this  code I impletement to get LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink
    }​​​​​​​​
    insert newTask;
    
    if(insertTask.isEmpty())
    {​​​​​​​​
    try{​​​​​​​​
    
    }​​​​​​​​catch(DmlException de)
    {​​​​​​​​
    System.debug(de);
    }​​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​​​
```

I need to assign LinkedEntityId this id to create task.
Trigger -> WhoId.

Is anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `ContentDocumentLink` nor `ContentDocument` exist upon insert of a new `ContentVersion` in response to a file upload. `ContentDocument` is the automatically-generated parent object of `ContentVersion`, and `ContentDocumentLink` is a pseudo-junction object that connects `ContentDocument` to records where it is shared.

I'd recommend taking a look at the [Content ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm). These objects are quite complicated to work with, both because the data model is complex and because several of the objects have unique behaviors.

Your code at is stands isn't valid; you have a number of syntax errors, logic errors, and bulkification issues. I'd strongly recommend you complete the [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) module on Trailhead, especially the Bulk Apex Triggers unit, to learn how to structure a good trigger.

---

It appears that your goal is to add a Task when a file is attached with its WhoId or WhatId set based upon the record to which the file was attached. If that is correct, you don't need `ContentDocument` or `ContentDocumentLink`. The `ContentVersion` object has a field called `FirstPublishLocationId`. When a `ContentVersion` is created by a file upload, that field is populated with the record Id to which it will be attached. You'll be able to build your logic on that basis without querying anything.